# Do i need the worklight license for developing push notification?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

[This link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_worklight_to_send_push_notifications76?lang=en) says `Configure Worklight to use the correct credentials for sending push notifications.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence is not talking about a Worklight license.

In order to send push notifications you need credentials from the vendor from which the notifications will be sent.

In the case of Google, those will be the GCM key and project number.
In the case of Apple, you'll need to supply a certificate and its password.

Please follow up-to-date guides instead of articles from 2013...

To familiarize yourself with push notification in MobileFirst Platform/Worklight, read the Getting Started tutorials: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/

How to setup your Apple Developer account and the push certificate is unrelated to Worklight/MFP. You can find many guides on the web (that are more up to date) explaining how you can do that.